# How to use delicious API from command line

Tags: wget, curl, api, delicious

I'm trying to add a delicious bookmark from a shell script, but keep getting the mysterious "something went wrong" error. I've checked the [official spec](http://www.delicious.com/developers#title1) and [several examples](http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/using_the_delicious_api/) and everything looks right. Any ideas?

```
wget --no-check-certificate --http-user=MYUSERNAME --http-passwd=MYPASSWORD https://api.del.icio.us/v1/posts/add?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwebmonkey.com%2F&description=The%20Internets%20Best%20Singles%20Hangout
```

also tried

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://MYUSERNAME:MYPASSWORD@api.del.icio.us/v1/posts/add?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwebmonkey.com%2F&description=The%20Internets%20Best%20Singles%20Hangout
```

Comment: what distro and version of wget?

Comment: "GNU Wget 1.13.4 built on darwin10.8.0." On OSX 10.6.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works using curl:

```
curl "https://MYUSERNAME:MYPASSWORD@api.del.icio.us/v1/posts/add?&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwebmonkey.com%2F&description=xxx&tags=test&replace=no"
```

[Solution found via this post](http://txt.binnyva.com/2009/06/post-to-delicious-from-command-line/). Still can't get wget to work, however.